# Why "fail" in promise does not catch errors?

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, promise, winjs

I'm trying to access a file, that might not exist:

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

localFolder.getFileAsync(stateFile).then(function (file) {
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (text) {
        // do something with the text

    });
}, function (err) {
    // log error, load dummy data

});
```

if the file is not there, the "fail" method does get called, BUT it happens only AFTER my application halts with an exception "file not found". only when I press "continue" for the debugger does it continue to the "fail" method..

what am i doing wrong? should i check for existence beforehand?

Comment: why then is there a fail method? i'm a bit lost here.. :)

Comment: forget it, I thought you were talking about promise of jQuery. Sorry.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that WinJS Promise == jQuery promise when it comes to behavior..

Comment: if the behaviour is the same of jQuery, `fail` is only checking the state of the related promise (rejected or resolved) and it's not handling internal exceptions/errors

Comment: yeah, but that's the thing. the fail() method DOES gets called, so obviously it's meant to catch it as well. only an exception is thrown... I can't understand even where to put the try-catch in that aspect - i thought async programming made try catch less useful

Comment: Your debugger is probably set to halt on first chance exceptions.  That means it's going to break into the debugger before the exception is processed.

Comment: huh. but as a developer I need to see first change exceptions as well.. so i can't turn it off, can i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a first-chance exception. The debugger is breaking at the point of throw. If you hit the "continue" button on the debugger dialog, the app will keep running and the exception handler will run.

You can change this by using the "Debug|Exceptions" menu to turn off first chance exceptions.

Comment: you're right, but i can't turn "first chance exceptions" off as a developer, can I? so am i bound to see this error message everytime?

Comment: Sure you can. Go to the Debug menu, Exceptions menu item. In the dialog, you should see a treeview. Under "JavaScript Runtime Exceptions", turn off the checkboxes in the "Thrown" column and that'll turn off the break on first chance exceptions. You will probably want to remember where this checkbox is, though - first chance exceptions come in handy when tracking down issues in async code.

Comment: but that's *exactly* my point. i know i *can* turn off that checkbox. i'm just saying that a developer, I *really* shouldn't. that's why the way your suggesting does not make sense to me :/

Comment: It's not hard & fast. First chance exceptions are really noisy. As such, I think it's better to run with them turned off until you see a problem. Then turn them back on, see if you're getting an exception, debug, and turn them back off again.

Comment: Without knowing about this "first chance" specific thing, I would've answered try/catch to ignore the Exception.  After all, it's implied that you want the fail() to handle a non-existent file.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this same problem for two or three days and finally came to the following solution: I use getFilesAsync function to get the list of all files in a folder, and then look through this list to know if the needed file exists. After that I can call getFileAsyns without throwing. Not very pretty, but works for me. I agree that assuming that a developer can turn exceptions off is not the best advice... In my opinion this issue should be considered as a bug in RT implementation.